# Java/Android FeedParser - Add one more Menu Item

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

Downloaded this Source Code: https://github.com/shikha14/ParsingRssFeeds

I want to add more menu items, but it don´t work...

The original code in

AppUtils.java

```
public class AppUtils {

public static final String RSS_CNN_NEWS = "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_latest.rss";
public static final String RSS_GOOGLE_NEW = "https://news.google.com/?output=rss";
public static final String TAG = "DIGIPLUSE";
```

and Api.java:

```
 public void getNews(int position, FetchListener listener) {
    String url = null;
    if (position == 0) {
        url = AppUtils.RSS_CNN_NEWS;
    } else {
        url = AppUtils.RSS_GOOGLE_NEW;
    }
    new AsyncHTTPPost().execute(url, listener);
}
```

I try this:

```
public class AppUtils {

public static final String RSS_1 = "http://example.org/feed&type=rss";
public static final String RSS_2 = "http://example.org/feed&type=rss";
public static final String RSS_3 = "http://example.org/feed&type=rss";
public static final String RSS_4 = "http://example.org/feed&type=rss";
```

and this:

```
public void getNews(int position, FetchListener listener) {
String url = null;
if (position == 0) {
url = AppUtils.RSS_1;
} else {
url = AppUtils.RSS_2;
url = AppUtils.RSS_3;
url = AppUtils.RSS_4;
}
```

When i start the app, it display the 4 items, but the url work only for the first and second menu items...
have anyone a idea?

Thanks for answers...

Answer (score 0):

Your code, in the question, has only two conditions: `if (position == 0)` and `else`.   You need to handle the additional positions.  Also, in your 'else' block you assign the value of AppUtils.RSS_2 to the local variable url.  Then you assign AppUtils.RSS_3 to url, which replaces the value that it previously referenced.  Then you repeat for AppUtils.RSS_4.  That won't achieve anything, since each of your assignments overwrote the effects of the previous one.

Assuming you actually created the menu items (your question doesn't contain anything about that), then handle them:

```
if (position == 0) {
    url = AppUtils.RSS_1;
} else if (position == 1) {
    url = AppUtils.RSS_2;
} else if (position == 2) {
    url = AppUtils.RSS_3;
} else if (position == 3) {
    url = AppUtils.RSS_4;
} else {
    throw new IllegalArugmentException("Unrecognized position: "+position);
}
```